# Swift presentViewController completion block working only in debug not called in release

Tags: swift, closures, completion-block

I have a strange behaviour with a completion block in Debug and Release.
For example:

```
        sourceViewController.presentViewController(ccVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: kChromeCastInstructionsShown)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println("save bolean")
        })
```

In debug:
   println("save bolean") print string
In relase:
 println("save bolean") print nothing

Any idea about this behaviour?
Someone experiment a clear solution?

Kind
Andrea

Comment: Yes same problem here!

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode 6.3 fixed this.

Answer (score 10):

It looks a Swift compiler bug (at least version 1.1) discussed here:
https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1632

In a release build, closures are not invoked sometimes especially when they are sequenced like:

```
array.map({ $0 * 2 }).map({ $0 * 3 }).map({ $0 * 4 })...
```

The problem appears in Swift only, not in Objective-C. It can be workarounded by setting Swift Compiler Optimization Level to **None [-Onone]** if your app does not require the better performance by the optimization.

[image: Screenshot]

Or another workaround is naming the closure as a function:

```
func completionHandler() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: kChromeCastInstructionsShown)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    println("save bolean")
}

sourceViewController.presentViewController(ccVC, animated: true, completion: completionHandler)
```

I take the former workaround for my project because I want to keep my code simple and don't need the performance enhancement by the optimization.

Comment: You saved me nearly 2 years later !

Answer (score 0):

I notice the same problem in xcode 7  . 
For example

```
  let delay = 0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {



            })
```

works only if i also set optimimizazion level None[-OO]